# How can I regularly get Google analytics data from accounts that have previously authorised my readonly access?

Tags: google-analytics

I am something of a Google Analyitcs novice.

I have a PHP website that allows client to add their website names in order to advertise for services. When they add a website they own they have to validate it by allowing my server to login to their google analytics via the standard OAUTH permission screen etc, find their property and read their number of visits for the last month. The authorisation is stored in a session access token as $_SESSION['access_token'], which is then lost as soon as the session is closed or the user cleans out their browser. I think Google calls this a "web server application".

The problem is I would now like to run a cron every day on my server that accesses the google analytics of each of these customers who have authorised me and downloads the last days visitor numbers in order to be able to display them on the website. The problem I have is obviously I cannot be asking for the users OAUTH permission because it is occuring every day and without the user being present.

1) Would this new use case that does not require OAUTH and the users presence if they have already previously authorised me be a different type of application? What google analytics calls a "Service application"?

2) If it were a different type of application such as "service application" would I be able to loginto these accounts to pull the readonly data already authorised in the previous OAUTH web application, without requiring any further user input. Basically do the authorisations previously granted transfer over to a different type of application if I limit myself to using the same email address and using only the readonly properties I was granted access to?

I would appreciate any pointers or help - thanks.

Comment: Just read this on Google Analytics API: Web Server- This flow is good for automated, offline, or scheduled access of a user's Google Analytics data.

Example:

Automatically updating user dashboards with the latest Google Analytics data.
Note: The user must complete a one-time auth flow to grant your application offline access to their Google Analytics data. Afterwards, a refresh token can be used to obtain a new access token.

Comment: So it seems I could use the WEB SERVER APPLICATION but request a refresh token instead of a new one?

Answer (score 0):

So in the end I solved this by setting up OAUTH for a web app and then using refresh tokens to avoid having to ask for authorisation each time.